$H^*(U(n);k) \cong H^*(\mathfrak{gl}_n(k);k)$ proof for $k$ a field of characteristic zero
There's an old result in Lie theory that gives an isomorphism $H^*(U(n);k) \cong H^*(\mathfrak{gl}_n(k);k)$ of cohomology rings for $k$ a field of characteristic $0$. Here, $\mathfrak{gl}_n(k)$ refers to a Lie algebra, and $U(n)$ refers to the Lie group of $n \times n$ unitary matrices.
Does anyone know where I can find a proof of this?
Thanks!

We have $H^*(U(n)) \cong \Lambda[c_1,c_3,\ldots,c_{2n-1}]$ by using spectral sequences, and this exterior algebra is also obtained for the cohomology of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{gl}_n(k)$. References are given here, for example, and the book by A. L. Onishchik, E. B. Vinberg: Lie groups and algebraic groups.
